# How to Run Jave script in edge browser using java and selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, microsoft-edge

i want run below code in edge browser using java selenium project

```
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitSeconds);
    // wait for page complete
    //log.debug("PageLoadState>>"+pageLoadCondition.toString());
    
    // Wait for Javascript to load    
                
      ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = driver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString()
              .equals("complete");
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
      boolean jsReady = (Boolean) js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");

      // Wait Javascript until it is Ready!
      if (!jsReady) {
          // System.out.println("JS in NOT Ready!");
          wait.until(jsLoad);
      }
```

we are getting exception in below line as  **Exception class:org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException
the reason is:org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Function is not a constructor**

```
boolean jsReady = (Boolean) js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
```

We set edgeoption as below

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        
        
        desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName("MicrosoftEdge");
        
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
        edgeOptions.setCapability("ms:inPrivate", true);
    //  edgeOptions.setCapability("prefs", edgePrefs);
        edgeOptions.setCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);


        edgeOptions.merge(desiredCapabilities);
        edgeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy("eager");
        edgeOptions.setCapability("ms:inPrivate", true);
        edgeOptions.setCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
        edgeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
        edgeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.HAS_NATIVE_EVENTS, true);
        

        driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
```

Pls advise is any other way to run the javascript in edge using java and selenium

Comment: I see that you have posted the same issue in several threads. I suggest that you focus on one thread so that we won't be confused. Which version of Edge browser and Edge WebDriver do you use? Besides, please use the latest version of Edge, Selenium and Java and test again. I use this code and it works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD4IT.png.